# Sharepoint 2010: Controlling the WYSIWYG with script

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

SharePoint is a beast and seems to stomp on everything. Customizing the front-end with javascript has gone well, but now I would like to provide my content owners with more back-end controls. However, any changes made to objects in the WYSIWYG editable area at $(document).ready are immediately reverted by SharePoint.

I imagine this has to do with that "content" not really existing there, but being a copy of hidden input fields. Does anyone know how to get some control of this area? I would love to be able to insert or modify "page content" under the control of scripts, but SharePoint documentation is so terrifyingly sparse.

*EDIT: It appears as though content which is inserted "late" (as in html which is inserted by a click event well after page load) will stick. Anything done at doc.ready or window.load however is rinsed before the area is relinquished to user control.

Comment: Do you mean you want to insert ready-made HTML into a rich content box at edit time? Should you not instead be writing a custom web part? I feel your pain regarding documentation, or indeed, where to start to get a handle on things!

Comment: Don't get me started on web parts ;) Our shop does not currently have access to Visual Studio or much farm control at all. Everything we have done has been through the magic of jQuery. This means the front-end looks great, but the "reusable content" we provide our content owners is finicky and easy to ruin. I would like to "insert"  content in the back-end on-the-fly with javascript. Basically redesign the WYSIWYG without touching it directly!

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint does a lot of "Sanitizing" of Content entered into some HTML Fields or Content Editor Web Parts sadly. Can you edit the Master Page through SharePoint designer and stick your JavaScript in there?

Also look at [ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60348/SharePoint-2010-Client-Object-Model-for-JavaScript.aspx) or [_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push()](http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/andrevala/archive/2007/12/16/WSS-Tip-_2300_19_3A00_-Using-JavaScript-in-Body-OnLoad-Event.aspx)

Comment: Definitely. Most of the Javascript I write goes in the page-layouts, but this is functionally similar to being in the masterpage. The problem is the "when" to do things. Content added to the editable field by script at document ready will flash into existence momentarily then be promptly removed by SharePoint. 
However, things that are added "later" will survive. Unless I can find a way to add content AFTER sharepoint is finished being stupid, and BEFORE the user start doing stuff I will be severely limited in what controls I can offer to the user in edit-mode.

Comment: @Sinetheta I've added two possible JavaScript functions that can help you. I don't fully understand the problem you are having, but I ran into SharePoint load order issues myself.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into there. On first attempt they won't save the scripts. Under ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded they execute as normal, during the "garbage SP flicker phase"(where the ribbon tries to drunkenly decide where to sit) and then everything gets crushed as though you just fired them as usual. _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push() Doesn't seem to execute them at all (no errors, just no scripts).
It's like wrestling in the dark with a hippo, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Sinetheta The ribbon is part of `sp.ui.js`, so maybe passing that in as the last parameter to ExecuteOrDelay would work (instead of `sp.js` as in the article)

Comment: That one must load even sooner, because with it I don't even get the fake-out execution. At least sp.js gave a little tease "hey look, I instantiated your jquery ui items, PSYCH!"